# Smart Sheet API 2.1.1, Download attachment but url is missing

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2, smartsheet-java-sdk-v1, smartsheet-api-2.0

### Download attachement to Local drive ##

```
        for(Row r : rows){

        PagedResult<Attachment> attachments = smartsheet.sheetResources().rowResources().attachmentResources().getAttachments(sheetId, r.getId(), null);


        System.out.println("attachments"+attachments.getData().size());


        if(attachments.getData().size() > 0){

        for(Attachment at : attachments.getData()){

                      System.out.println(String.format("Attachement ID[%s], URL{%s}",at.getId(),at.getUrl()));

        }
```

Output::

- Attachement ID[2625191160375172], URL{null}
- Attachement
  ID[3215061968807812], URL{null}
- Attachement ID[6310196327802756],
  URL{null}
- Attachement ID[5565993922652036], URL{null}

Comment: I want to download attachement associated with row, sheet or anything. i have trial account but i don't think that would be the problem.

Comment: According to official [documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-attachment) 


GET /sheets/{sheetId}/attachments/{attachmentId}

Fetches the Attachment specified in the URL.

Access Scope READ_SHEETS
Headers Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Returns Attachment object. For File attachments, this will include a temporary URL for downloading the file.

Currently, the temporary URL is set to expire in 120000 milliseconds, or 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now, iterating the object and reaching out the attachement will not give you the url, infact you have to get id from that object and then query smart sheet again with GetAttachment procedure i. e

```
  Attachment at = smartsheet.sheetResources().attachmentResources().getAttachment(sheetId, att.getId());
```